# javascript not reading PHP variable correctly in window.open

Tags: javascript, php, html, button

I have a very simple table where I'm retrieving income information for some people.
The table retrieves data correctly and the link to the file in stored in a variable, like this:

```
$file = "/".$row[9];
```

Where $row comes from the while loop. I have a button inside the table:

```
<button id = "openbtn" class = 'actionbtn' onClick = "window.open('<?php echo $file;?>')" title = 'Open Attachment'><i class='fa fa-file'></i></button>
```

If I create a new variable where I manually set the link:

```
$file2 = '/folder1/folder2/somename.pdf';
```

then the button will open fine. But it will not work with $file , I get Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token.

Any clue?

Comment: Look at what is generated in the browser.... inspect the element, look what the php code is spitting out.

Comment: I did, in fact $file2 is created based on echo $file one; any chance there is hidden characters that I can't see and javascript catches? anyway to "clean" the string/

Comment: What is it? copy and paste what is generated....

Comment: /scans/migrated/4099_20046_INCOME_23594.pdf

Comment: I even tried trimming the string and still doesn't work

Comment: What does `onClick = "window.open('<?php echo $file;?>')"` actually look like in the source code of the browser when you inspect it?

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($row as $myfile){
   echo '<button
                 id="openbtn"
                 class="actionbtn"
                 title="Open Attachment"
                 onclick="window.open('."'$myfile'".');"
                 >
                 <i class='fa fa-file'></i>
         </button>';
}
```

try this loop

Comment: I did have the " , but not the ; and no, still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

A combination for trim($file) and changing the "" did it:

```
<button id = "openbtn" class = 'actionbtn' onClick = 'window.open(<?php echo '"'.$file .'"';?>);' title = 'Open Attachment'><i class='fa fa-file'></i></button>
```